# Bootstrap: align form labels in different rows

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm doing a form using Bootstrap 3.3.2 and I'm having problems aligning labels of diferent rows when the elements have diferent col-xs-*

[Bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/P1WGeoxJcM)

What I need is the `Bar` and `Faa` labels to get aligned as well as the `Bar`'s field with `Faa`'s and `Bor`'s ones maintaining the sizes and positions of the fields (`Bar`'s field is double in size ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that you're using both `form-group` and `col-xs-*` classes on the same div.

What you need is to wrap each `form-group` in another `div` with the `col-xs-*`.

I've fixed your code:

[Bootply fixed][1]

[1]: http://www.bootply.com/yDbREoFh2v

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thnx ;)

Comment: I think it's important to note, that this only works if you have an even number of bootstrap columns.